# How to style the script output in html?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I style my output from js function. I want that color was white, position in center.

I try to write after innerHTML=+x+

```js
function getNumber(){
    var x = document.getElementById("value-number").value
    document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML=x

}
```

```html
<div style="margin-left:30px";>
  <select id = "value-number">
    <option value="5555-555">Kate</option>
    <option value="4444-444">My</option>
  </select>
  <button onclick="getNumber()"> Show me </button>
</div>

<p id="numbers"></p>
```

Comment: The same way you style part of the DOM that was generated from HTML instead of JavaScript. Voting to close the question as "too broad". There's no sign of any CSS in the question at all.

Comment: MDN has some [introductory guides to CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS).

Comment: I am beginner in html. I can't find answer to my question anywhere. And what is the problem for you if I try to find for my question here? Why do you think that there's no sign of any css? By CSS , I think, I can style my output from javascript function.

Comment: "Why do you think that there's no sign of any css? " — Because in your live demo there is code in the HTML box and code in the JS box but none in the CSS box.

Comment: "By CSS , I think, I can style my output from javascript function" — Yes, CSS can style the output of the JS. I said that in my first comment. Try writing some CSS.

Comment: @Quentin so I added some css

Comment: The CSS you've added doesn't seem to be related to your problem. Any introductory CSS tutorial should explain how to change the text color and alignment inside a pagraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**.style**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) is used to add the required CSS properties to the element

```js
function getNumber(){
    var x = document.getElementById("value-number").value
    var elm = document.getElementById("numbers")
    elm.innerHTML = x
    elm.style.backgroundColor = '#F00'
    elm.style.olor = '#0F0'
}
```

```html
<div class="picker">
    <select id = "value-number">
        <option value="5555-555">Kate</option>
        <option value="4444-444">My</option>
    </select>
    <button onclick="getNumber()"> Show me </button>
</div>

<p id="numbers"></p>
```

Alternatively you can add `CSS` class which I prefer more.

```js
function getNumber(){
    var x = document.getElementById("value-number").value
    var elm = document.getElementById("numbers")
    elm.innerHTML = x
    elm.classList.add('my-style')
}
```

```css
.my-style {
    background-color: #F00;
    color: #0F0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="picker">
    <select id = "value-number">
        <option value="5555-555">Kate</option>
        <option value="4444-444">My</option>
    </select>
    <button onclick="getNumber()"> Show me </button>
</div>

<p id="numbers"></p>
```

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score -1):

try

```
document.getElementById("numbers").style.color = "white";

document.getElementById("numbers").style.textAlign = "center";
```

Comment: Avoid using the inline `style` property. A real stylesheet is prefered.

Comment: `center` is not a valid value for the `position` property and will be ignored.